# How to search for a number in a list of arrays of numbers based on the first index of each array using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of arrays of numbers. I am searching for the two arrays where my search number falls between the numbers positioned in index 0. Then return the number positioned in index 1 from the second array. (Assume numbers in index 0 are sorted already and there are no duplicates)

My wrong solution for LINQPad:

The value of 'found' should  be 3 because 9 falls between 4 & 10 in second and third array. Then I take the second found array and return 3 which is in index 1 of that array.

```
List<int[]> list = new List<int[]> { new[] { 1, 5 }, new[] { 4, 6 }, new[] { 10, 3} , new[] { 15, 8} };
int searchFor = 9;
int found = list.Where(n => searchFor >= n[0] && searchFor <= n[0]).Select(i => i[1]).FirstOrDefault();
found.Dump(); //should be 3 instead of 0.
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault has [an overload that accepts a lambda expression as a predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx).  Might make your life a little simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this :

```
int found = list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (x, y) => x[0]<=searchFor&&y[0]>=searchFor?y[1]:0).FirstOrDefault(o=>o!=0);
```

Comment: Or this: `list.SkipWhile(n => n[0] < searchFor).Select(n => n[1]).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

Well my logic is a little different, but get the result you want. I would recommend just using a Dictionary if you are doing key-pair-value stuff like this. It makes things simpler in my opinion and if you have no repeating key's this should work fine.

```
 // Use dictionary instead of array's if just using two int values
 var dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
 dic.Add(1, 5);
 dic.Add(4, 6);
 dic.Add(10, 3);
 dic.Add(15, 8);

 int searchFor = 9;

 // Don't need to find this really
 int low = (from l in dic
           where l.Key <= searchFor
           select l.Key).Max();

 // Just need this       
 int found = (from h in dic
             where h.Key >= searchFor
             select h.Value).Min();


 Console.WriteLine("Low: " + low);
 Console.WriteLine("Found: " + found);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
        var found = list.First(l => l[0] > searchFor)[1];
```

It should do the trick as I can assume that `list` is ordered by each first element.

If not, then

```
        var found = list.Orderby(l=>l[0]).First(l => l[0] > searchFor)[1];
```

should also work.

Comment: This gives an InvalidOperationException if number is not found and a null object reference if FirstOrDefault is used.

Comment: What should happen when there is no solution? I think an exception is perfectly alright.

Answer (score 0):

The expression in the where statement filters for arrays having the first element **less or equal and greater or equal** than 9. Since it can't be less **and** greater at the same time it actually filters for all arrays that have 9 as first element.
For the given data this results in an empty sequence. FirstOrDefault therefore returns the default (0 for integers).

You actually have to look for the first element greater or equal than 9:

```
int[] result = list.FirstOrDefault(arr => arr[0] >= searchFor);

if (result == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not found!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(result[1]);
}
```